# how to get the data from entity frame join tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using `entity frame work`. I create a function using 3 tables.

this is my code:

```
public static IQueryable GetMenuContent()
{            
    string roleName ="ADMIN"

    var query1 = from ua in db.USER_ACCESS
                 join p in db.PAGES on ua.PAGE_ID equals p.PAGE_ID
                 join r in db.ROLES on ua.ROLE_ID equals r.RoleId
                 where (r.RoleName == roleName)
                 select new
                 {
                     tuserAccess = ua,
                     tpage = p,
                     trole = r,
                 };            

    return query1;
}
```

So in my master page I need to check the `USER_ACCESS` table -> `PAGE_NAME`.

So I try like this

```
@foreach (var item in pro.Models.SiteContentModel.GetMenuContent())
{
      switch (((DAL.PAGES)(item)).PAGE_NAME)
      {
           case "details":
                if (((DAL.USER_ACCESS)(item)).ACC_STATUS == true)
                {
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("details", "Index", "Business")</li>
                }
                break;                
       }
}
```

but it is not working..
How can I do it..

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an exception? Or no <li> element? Can you check if your query1 contains any elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifiyi g the method as follow.
Your anonymous objcet's property accsing is changed.

**((DAL.t_PAGES)(item)).tpage.PAGE_NAME
((DAL.USER_ACCESS)(item)).tuserAccess.ACC_STATUS**

```
@foreach (var item in pro.Models.SiteContentModel.GetMenuContent())
{
      switch (((DAL.t_PAGES)(item)).tpage.PAGE_NAME)
      {
           case "details":
                if (((DAL.USER_ACCESS)(item)).tuserAccess.ACC_STATUS == true)
                {
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("details", "Index", "Business")</li>
                }
                break;                
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use navigation properties instead of joins in your case.

But in your case you should rewrite your foreach:

```
@foreach (var item in pro.Models.SiteContentModel.GetMenuContent())
{
      switch (item.tpage.PAGE_NAME)
      {
           case "details":
                if (item.tuserAccess.ACC_STATUS == true)
                {
                     <li>@Html.ActionLink("details", "Index", "Business")</li>
                }
                break;                
       }
}
```